# Do not execute following code if error callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a REST api and I've defined this error handler:

```
function handleError(res, reason, message, code) {
  console.log("ERROR: " + reason);
  res.status(code || 500).json({"error": message});
}
```

But I think it needs some kind of interruption so that the following code is not executed, because if I implement my post method like this:

```
app.post("/contacts", function(req, res) {
  var newContact = req.body;
  newContact.createDate = new Date();

  if (!(req.body.firstName || req.body.lastName)) {
    handleError(res, "Invalid user input", "Must provide a first or last name.", 400);
  }
  db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).insertOne(newContact, function(err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to create new contact.");
      } else {
        res.status(201).json(doc.ops[0]);
      }
    });
});
```

The server crashes and the invalid insertion is made into the database. I could solve this problem with an else for the insertion part, but I wanted to know if there is a way of not doing the rest of the method if the function handleError gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `return` after call `handleError` function

```
  //
  if (!(req.body.firstName || req.body.lastName)) {
    handleError(res, "Invalid user input", "Must provide a first or last name.", 400);
    return;
  }
  //
```

Answer (score 1):

A `return` statement will stop the rest of the function being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Simply edit your handleError function so that the last line will be:

```
 return res.status(code || 500).json({"error": message});
```

Or, in your /contacts handler :

```
if (!(req.body.firstName || req.body.lastName)) {
    return handleError(res, "Invalid user input", "Must provide a first or last name.", 400);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obvious answer is `return` or if somewhere higher up in the call stack you have error handling, `throw`ing is also valid flow control, but depending on your use-case, there might be a cleaner method.

I'm guessing you are using express. Check [this](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) out.